# Is it safe to put a PS4 in checked luggage?

Tags: luggage, electronic-items, check-in

My friend is coming back to India from Dubai and is bringing a PS4 for me, as it is cheaper there. It is new and in the original, unopened packaging. He has his own carry-on baggage and adding the PS4 would exceed the weight limit. Would it be safe from either damage or theft to pack it in his checked luggage?

Comment: You would make a TSA agent or baggage handler’s family very happy. /s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly safe (external damage/theft) to bring gaming consoles in checked-in baggage. Just pack it well and if possible, ask the person at airport check-in desk to put a fragile sticker while checking-in the luggage.

Disclaimer: I should not be held responsible if you end up with a bricked console but people do it all the time.

Comment: Safe from baggage theft? You must live in a different world from most of us.

Answer (score 2):

Never put anything of value in check-in luggage.
No airline and no insurer will pay for damages and loss, and there are many options for things to disappear from your luggage.

It is also not a good plan to transport anything in check-in luggage if is likely to get damaged when thrown, as all luggage, even with Fragile stickers, is often handled in such a way that it is likely to break.